# Debezium connector with column.include.list

Tags: database, apache-kafka, stream, debezium

How do I combine table.include.list and column.include.list in Debezium connector configuration if I need to snapshot part of one table and full data from another table?

Example connector configuration:

```
"table.include.list":"schema.table1, schema.table2",
"column.include.list":"schema.table1.col1, schema.table1.col2"
```

With this I get all columns of table1 in kafka.

Only managed how to do it using different connectors.

I want to get all columns from table2 and 2 columns from table1 using one connector, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
"table.include.list":"schema\.table1,schema\.table2",
"column.include.list":"schema\.table1\.{col1|col2},schema\.table2\..*"
```

Answer (score 1):

From Debezium documentation for **column.include.list** configuration attribute:

> An optional, comma-separated list of regular expressions that match the fully-qualified names of columns to include in change event record values. Fully-qualified names for columns are of the form databaseName.tableName.columnName.

So you have to configure 2 things:

1. *fully qualified table name* in the **table_include_list** attribure (which is also a comma-separated **list of regular expressions**)
2. *fully qualified column names* in the **column_include_list** attribure

If you want to include all columns from table, then configuration of column names in the **column_include_list** attribute is not necessary.

For example:

```
{
    ...
    "table.include.list": "schema\\.table1,schema\\.table2",
    "column.include.list": "schema\\.table1\\.(col1|col2)"
    ...
}
```

Column exclusion is configured in the same way, but using the **column_exclude_list** attribute.

See details here (i.e. for MySQL connector, other connectors are similar): https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-table-include-list